# How to prevent duplicate record to insert in database using spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to insert record in db using spring MVC.I put id as a primary key but i want when i insert duplicate email that time record should not be added in database.

Comment: Try to read the value from DB and if it exists send your email.

Comment: So email should be unique?

Answer (score 2):

Try to make your 'email' column unique (read how 
[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key#Defining_unique_keys))

Then (if you use JDBC for example) you must surround your SQL request with 'try-catch block' to handle SQLException